# Change NSTime with respect to the value of UISlider

Tags: iphone, nstimer, uislider

There are lots of questions and answers about how to change the `UISlider` value with `NsTimer` but i need to create the reverse condition i need to change the `NSTimer` interval per `UISlider` value change, and want the slider value work in reverse manner. so can anyone help to achieve this?

Thanks for your approaches and time :)

Answer (score 1):

you can set Timer set again interval value at the `IBAction` of `UISlier` Method like:-

**.h class:-**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

    IBOutlet UILabel *lblTimer;
    IBOutlet UISlider *timeSlider;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSTimer *timer;
```

**.m class:-**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _timer=[[NSTimer alloc]init];
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateLable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
int i=0;
-(IBAction)changeSlider:(UISlider*)sender
{

    NSLog(@"%d",(int)sender.value);
    [_timer invalidate];

    _timer=[[NSTimer alloc]init];

    _timer=nil;
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(int)sender.value target:self selector:@selector(updateLable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
   // i=0;
    //text_field .text= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" Value %d ", (int)slider.value];
}


-(void)updateLable
{

    [lblTimer setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    i++;

}
```

**OUTPUT OF CODE**

[image]

Comment: and i need slider to work in reverse manner like i am blinking flashlight per timer so need to go with min to max but slider value min is max rate of blinking so i need it in reverse manner

Comment: Check my Upadted Answer

Comment: great work man thanks +1 for your efforts but as you can see if you min the slider label changes value fast but i need exact reverse.

Comment: that is logical that you need to set with some condition sir and are you asking that to want to set slider wise timer time interal

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38469/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-d-eptdeveloper)